# waypoints don't work correctly until window resized

Tags: jquery-waypoints

Waypoints plugin don't work correctly until I resize a window. I dont know why and can't find a reason of this problem.
After window resize all became right.

Here is part of my code:

```
$(function)(){
//menu active change while scroll
var about_us = $("section.about-us");
waypoints = about_us.waypoint(function(direction){

    console.log("about_us section");
    changeActiveMenu("about_us-menu");

    if (direction === 'down') {
        $(".to-top").addClass("show");
        console.log("show-to-top");
    }else if (direction === 'up') {
        $(".to-top").removeClass("show");
        console.log("hide-to-top");
    }

},{
    offset: "30%"
});


var building = $("section.building");
waypoints = building.waypoint(function(){
    console.log("building section");

    changeActiveMenu("building-menu", "service-menu");
},{
    offset: "30%"
});
});
```

here is a link with problem: http://sandbox.maximshadrin.ru/aquanomika/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was in a code order. I was initialized sliders after initialize waypoint and $(html).height() parameter was wrong, because height contains all slides(one upon another instead one next to lhe left).
So I has concluded: "Always init waypoints on the bottom part of your code"